# Definition of determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, permutations, determinant

$\newcommand{\b}{\mathbf}$
Let columns of $A_{n \times n}$ be $\b v_1, ..., \b v_n$,

$$\b v_k = \sum^{n}_{r = 1} a_{r,k} \b e_r$$ $a_{r,k}$ are the elements of $\b v_k$.

$$\det A := D(\b v_1, ..., \b v_n) = \sum^n_{r_1 = 1} ...\sum_{r_n = 1}^n a_{r_1, 1}a_{r_2, 2} ... a_{r_n, n}\cdot  D(\b e_{r_1}, ..., \b e_{r_n})$$

If $\operatorname{Perm} (n)$ is set of all permutations of set  $\{1, ..., n\}$,

$$\det A = \sum_{\sigma \in \operatorname{Perm} (n)} a_{\sigma(1), 1}...a_{\sigma(n), n} \cdot D(\b e_{\sigma(1)}, ..., \b e_{\sigma(n)})$$

Let $K(\sigma)$ be number of $(j, k) \in \{1, ..., n\},\ \ \  j < k :\sigma(j) > \sigma(k) $, then $\operatorname{sign} (\sigma) = (-1)^{K(\sigma)}$.

$$\det A = \sum_{\sigma \in \operatorname{Perm} (n)} a_{\sigma(1), 1}...a_{\sigma(n), n} \cdot \operatorname{sign}(\sigma).$$

---

I lost it at $\operatorname{sign} (\sigma)$, why does $K(\sigma)$ correspond to number of interchanges in $ D(\b e_{\sigma(1)}, ..., \b e_{\sigma(n)})$ for a given permutation $\sigma$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\sign{\operatorname{sign}}$

Possibly there are two questions here: (1)  Why is $\sign(\sigma) = (-1)^{K(\sigma)}$ ?  and (2)  Why is $\sign(\sigma) = D(e_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, e_{\sigma(n)})$?

For the first question:

Two arguments:  $K(e) = \sign(e) = 1$ and for an adjacent transposition $\sigma_i = (i, i+1)$, and for any permutation $\sigma$, we have
$K(\sigma_i \sigma) = K(\sigma) \pm 1$, while $\sign(\sigma_i \sigma) = (-1) \sign(\sigma)$, because $\sign$ is a homomorphism from the symmetric group to $\{\pm 1\}$ which takes the value $-1$ on a two cycle.

2nd argument:  draw any permutation as a diagram with two rows of dots, and the $i$-th dot on the top row connected to the $\sigma(i)$ dot on the bottom row.   Adjust your diagram so that the crossings occur at different vertical heights.  You have just expressed your permutation as a product of adjacent transpositions and the number of them is $K(\sigma)$, because each pair of strands crosses at most once, and the number of crossings is $K(\sigma)$.

For the second question: The answer to this sort of depends on how you, or your professor, or your textbook, defined $D(e_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, e_{\sigma(n)})$.  However it was done, though, you will have (1)
$D(e_1,\dots, e_n) = 1$ and (2)interchanging two columns changes $D(*)$ by a factor of $-1$.

But 
replacing $\sigma$ by $\sigma \sigma_i$ in $D(e_{\sigma_1}, \dots, e_{\sigma_n})$ means interchanging two columns, and thus changing $D(*)$ by a factor of $-1$.  It follows that $\sign(\sigma) = D(e_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, e_{\sigma(n)})$.

Comment: What's a homomorphism ? What's $e$ in $K(e)$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I used $e$ for the identity permutation, which leaves the numbers 1 to n in their original order.    It may have been inappropriate for me to mention "homomorphism" as you may not have that in your background.  Maybe you have to tell me how you are thinking of permutations and what is your preferred definition of the sign of a permutation.  There are various ways to go about these things, and I don't know where you are starting from.  Thus I don't know your definition of the sign of a permutation or your definition of $D(e_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, e_{\sigma(1)})$.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Every permutation can be decomposed into transpositions, which just switch two elements.

For example, $(1,2,3) \mapsto (2,3,1)$ is a permutation, but really it is $(12)(23)$.

$\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)$ is $(-1)^{ \mathrm{ number\, of\, transpositions}}$. Or, $(-1)^{K(\sigma)}$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071920/the-sign-function-is-a-homomorphism) for more details.

Here is an example of a $3 \times 3$ from Wikipedia:

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{det}(a_{ij})&=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,\sigma_i}\\
&=\mathrm{sgn}([1,2,3]) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,[1,2,3]_i} + \mathrm{sgn}([1,3,2]) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,[1,3,2]_i} + \mathrm{sgn}([2,1,3]) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,[2,1,3]_i} \\ &+ \mathrm{sgn}([2,3,1]) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,[2,3,1]_i} + \mathrm{sgn}([3,1,2]) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,[3,1,2]_i} + \mathrm{sgn}([3,2,1]) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,[3,2,1]_i}
\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,[1,2,3]_i} - \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,[1,3,2]_i} - \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,[2,1,3]_i} + \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,[2,3,1]_i} + \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,[3,1,2]_i} - \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,[3,2,1]_i}
\\
&=a_{1,1}a_{2,2}a_{3,3}-a_{1,1}a_{2,3}a_{3,2}-a_{1,2}a_{2,1}a_{3,3}+a_{1,2}a_{2,3}a_{3,1} \\
& \qquad +a_{1,3}a_{2,1}a_{3,2}-a_{1,3}a_{2,2}a_{3,1}.
\end{align*}